# Is "inline text" supposed to be visible in the spoiler tag?

Tags: bug, status-completed

> This is a spoiler with `visible inline text` which looks weird.

Is `inline text` supposed to be visible inside the spoiler tag like this? It is an interesting design feature if it is, otherwise I would call it a bug.

Comment: Whether a bug or not, that's really cool and I reckon it should stick around, as it allows you to hide big chunks of text while leaving non spoilers inside there, instead of having multiple spoiler chunks that makes the whole post look huge.

Comment: Given that e.g. on [metase] it's not visible, that's probably not intentional.

Comment: Do you guys want this "fixed?"

Comment: @JarrodDixon what does "'fixed'" mean?  Tagging this `[status-bydesign]`?

Comment: @NickT yeah, I was a bit ambiguous there - I meant making it the same as other sites, which would lose the coolness factor Mr Smooth mentioned.  But it looks like Jin has "fixed" it :)

Comment: @JarrodDixon why do you keep putting " 'fixed' " in quotes, that gives it sarcastic undertones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep it consistent with the other sites, I've made the code block invisible in the spoiler block by default. the change will be in the next production build.